# Year over Year Stats from a Crossfilter Dataset

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

### Summary

I want to pull out Year over Year stats in a Crossfilter-DC driven dashboard

### Year over Year (YoY) Definition

2017 YoY is the total units in 2017 divided by the total units in 2016.

### Details

I'm using `DC.js` (and therefore `D3.js` & `Crossfilter`) to create an interactive Dashboard that can also be used to change the data it's rendering.

I have data, that though wider (has ~6 other attributes in addition to date and quantity: size, color, etc...sales data), boils down to objects like:

```
[
 { date: 2017-12-7, quantity: 56,  color: blue  ...},
 { date: 2017-2-17, quantity: 104, color: red   ...},
 { date: 2016-12-7, quantity: 60,  color: red   ...},
 { date: 2016-4-15, quantity: 6,   color: blue  ...},
 { date: 2017-2-17, quantity: 10,  color: green ...},
 { date: 2016-12-7, quantity: 12,  color: green ...}
  ...
]
```

I'm displaying one rowchart per attribuet such that you can see the totals by color, size, etc. People would use each of these charts to be able to see the totals by that attribute and drill into the data by filtering by just a color, or a color and a size, or a size, etc. This setup is all (relatively) straight forward and kind of what DC is made for.

However, now I'd like to add some YoY stats such that I can show a barchart with x-axis as the years, and the y-axis as the YoY values (ex. YoY-2019 = Units-2019 / Units-2018). I'd also like to do the same by quarter and month such that I could see YoY Mar-2019 = Units-Mar-2019 / Units-Mar-2018 (and the same for quarter).

I have a year dimension and sum quantity

```
var yearDim = crossfilterObject.dimension(_ => _.date.getFullYear());
var quantityGroup = yearDim.group.reduceSum(_ => _.quantity);
```

I can't figure out how to do the Year over Year calc though in the nice, beautiful DC.js-way.

### Attempted Solutions

**Year+1**

Add another dimension that's year + 1. I didn't' really get any further though because all I get out of it are two dimensions whose year groups I want to divide ... but am not sure how.

```
var yearPlusOneDim = crossfilterObject.dimension(_ => _.date.getFullYear() + 1);
```

Visually I can graph the two separately and I know, conceptually, what I want to do: which is divide the 2017 number in yearDim by the 2017 number in YearPlusOneDim (which, in reality, is the 2016 number). But "as a concept is as far as I got on this one.

**Abandon DC Graphing**

I could always use the yearDim's quantity group to get the array of values, which I could then feed into a normal D3.js graph.

```
var annualValues = quantityGroup.all();
console.log(annualValues);
// output = [{key: 2016, value: 78}, {key: 2017, value: 170}]
// example data from the limited rows listed above
```

But this feels like a hacky solution that's bound to fail and not benefit from all the rapid and dynamic DC updating.

Comment: I'm a little lost - are you just trying to extract one number, total units for 2017 / total units for 2016? Are you going to draw a chart? If there's no chart, there's definitely no need for dc.js. I mean, you could put that one number in a [number display](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/number.html) but that's not all that exciting is it. If you want to extra a few YoY numbers for a chart, I can help you with that.

Comment: If you want to *extract a few YoY numbers and put them into a chart, then a fake group could help and I'd be glad to help with that. But it seems kind of silly for one number, so I'm trying to understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. You're right that I missed a few clarifying points. I currently have a DC bar graph for each attribute in my data set (color, size, etc.). The primary purpose is to show how our sales forecast breaks out by each of these. (I also have the annual numbers displayed so people can see how it breaks by year.)

Comment: The reason I'm using DC is so people can quick answer questions like "...and now how's it look just for Black...and now what about Black in 2019 only...etc. All the things DC is great for. Now that I've accomplished that, I wanted to add some YoY stats so that people could see that the forecast is increasing X% in 2019, but if you zoom into Black-8GB, it's actually 3% down YOY.

Comment: Sounds good, but specifically what do you want to display? An extra annotation on e.g. every bar in a bar chart? A single number that displays YoY for whatever is currently selected / filtered?

Comment: Another few bar charts. One that will have year on the x-axis and annual YoY on the y-axis. Then two of a similar vein, but by quarter and month, so if I'm looking at Mar-2019 (on the monthly one), the y-axis value would be = Total-Units-Mar-2019 / Total-Units-Mar-2018.

Comment: This is not simple. I would think a fake group would be the way to go as you would have access to the key, so you could look up your comparison value. I think you could also do this in the dc.js valueAccessor. Again, you could have to look up the comparison value based on the key that is being displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use a fake group, in order to solve this in one pass.

As @Ethan says, you could also use a value accessor, but then you'd have to look up the previous year each time a value is accessed - so you'd probably have to keep an extra table around. With a fake group, you only need this table in the body of your `.all()` function.

Here's a quick sketch of what the fake group might look like:

```
function yoy_group(group) {
    return {
        all: function() {
            // index all values by date
            var bydate = group.all().reduce(function(p, kv) {
                p[kv.key.getTime()] = kv.value;
                return p;
            }, {});
            // for any key/value pair which had a value one year earlier,
            // produce a new pair with the ratio between this year and last
            return group.all().reduce(function(p, kv) {
                var date = d3.timeYear.offset(kv.key, -1);
                if(bydate[date.getTime()])
                    p.push({key: kv.key, value: kv.value / bydate[date.getTime()]});
                return p;
            }, []);
        }
    };
}
```

The idea is simple: first index all the values by date. Then when producing the array of key/value pairs, look each one up to see if it had a value one year earlier. If so, push a pair to the result (otherwise drop it).

This should work for any date-keyed group where the dates have been rounded.

Note the use of [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) in a couple of places. This is the spiritual ancestor of crossfilter's `group.reduce` - it takes a function which has the same signature as the reduce-add function, and an initial value (not a function) and produces a single value. Instead of reacting to changes like the crossfilter one does, it just loops over the array once. It's useful when you want to produce an object from an array, or produce an array of different size from the original.

Also, when indexing an object by a date, I use [Date.getTime()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) to fetch the numeric representation of the date. Otherwise the date coerces to a string representation which may not be exact. Probably for this application it would be okay to skip `.getTime()` but I'm in the habit of always comparing dates exactly.

[Demo fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/7a9uw5ed/8/) of YOY trade volume in the data set used by the stock example on the main dc.js page.

Comment: This is great. Thanks Gordon! I was reviewing the fiddle you provided and on lines 32 & 36 you reduce a group (`var bydate = group.all().reduce(...`) using only two parameters. But when I read [the API](https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference#group_reduce) I thought you had to do all three: add, remove, initial. Also on line 39 you have `if(bydate[date.getTime()])`. Is that just to avoid a divide by zero error?

Comment: Good questions, I was thinking I should probably explain those two functions. I have done so.

Comment: `Array.reduce` ... Fascinating! I missed that it was being applied to `group.all()` (the array of group key-values) and not to the `group` itself. Regarding the "group wrapper", I've seen this same pattern before when you want to remove keys that have a value of zero (or near-zero) from a group (and then usually pair that with `elasticX/Y`). In this case, by overwriting the `all` function of the group ¿are we just manually dictating how each key-value pair is processed after they're created by the group's map-reduce?

Comment: It's not overwriting the group, it's a new wrapper object which acts just like a group for the purpose we need, which is just `group.all()`. (That's all that dc.js uses from the group.) And yes, it's a way to preprocess - when dc.js wants to draw it calls `.all()`. When the "fake group" responds it first calls `.all()` on the "real group" and then it can add, remove, and change the key/item pairs which `.all()` returns.

Comment: This was exactly the help I needed. Thanks @Gordon. I'm quite sure I'd have sat on this problem for a very long time and potentially never got there without the help. One change I made was inside of your second `reduce` function (in the `return` statement). Instead of creating a new Date and then decrementing it by a year and then using that in the if-clause, I merged the generation of the new date into a single step using d3's offset: `var date = d3.timeYear.offset(kv.key, -1)`

Answer (score 0):

I've rewritten @Gordon 's code below. All the credit is his for the solution (answered above) and I've just wirtten down my own version (far longer and likely only useful for beginners like me) of the code (much more verbose!) and the explanation (also much more verbose) to replicate my thinking in bridging my near-nothing starting point up to @Gordon 's really clever answer.

```
yoyGroup = function(group) {
  return { all: function() {
    // For every key-value pair in the group, iterate across it, indexing it by it's time-value
    var valuesByDate = group.all().reduce(function(outputArray, thisKeyValuePair) {
      outputArray[thisKeyValuePair.key.getTime()] = thisKeyValuePair.value;
      return outputArray;
    }, []);
    return group.all().reduce(function(newAllArray, thisKeyValuePair) {
        var dateLastYear = d3.timeYear.offset(thisKeyValuePair.key, -1);
        if (valuesByDate[dateLastYear.getTime()]) {
          newAllArray.push({
              key: thisKeyValuePair.key, 
            value: thisKeyValuePair.value / valuesByDate[dateLastYear.getTime()] - 1
          });
        }
        return newAllArray;
      }, []); // closing reduce() and a function(...)
  }}; // closing the return object & a function
};
```

**¿Why are we overwritting the `all()` function?**
When DC.js goes to create a graph based on a grouping, the only function from Crossfilter it uses is the `all()` function. So if we want to do something custom to a grouping to affect a DC graph, we only have to overwrite that one function: `all()`.

**¿What does the `all()` function need to return?**
A group's `all` function must return an `array` of `object`s and each `object` must have two properties: `key` & `value`.

**¿So what exactly are we doing here?**
We're starting with an existing group which shows some values over time (*Important Assumption*: keys are date objects) and then creating a wrapper around it so that we can take advantage of the work that crossfilter has already done to aggregate at a certain level (ex. year, month, etc.).

We start by using `reduce` to manipulate the array of objects into a more simple array where the keys and values that were in the objects are now directly in the array. We do this to make it easier to look up values by keys.

```
before / output structure of group.all()
[ {key: k1, value: v1},
  {key: k2, value: v2},
  {key: k3, value: v3}
]

after
[ k1: v1,
  k2: v2,
  k3: v3
]
```

Then we move on to creating the correct `all()` structure again: an `array` of `objects` each of which has a `key` & `value` property. We start with the existing group's `all()` array (once again), but this time we have the advantage of our `valuesByDate` array which will make it easy to look up other dates.

So we iterate (via `reduce`) over the original `group.all()` output and lookup in the array we generated earlier (`valuesByDate`), if there's an entry from one year ago (`valuesByDate[dateLastYear.getTime()]`). (We use `getTime()` so it's simple integers rather than objects we're indexing off of.) If there is an element of the array from one year ago, then we add a key-value object-pair to our soon-to-be-returned array with the current key (date) and for the value we divide the "now" value (`thisKeyValuePair.value`) by the value 1 year ago: `valuesByDate[dateLastYear.getTime()]`. Lastly we subtract 1 so that it's (the most traditional definition of) YoY. Ex. This year = 110 and last year = 100 ... YoY = +10% = 110/100 - 1.