# How to shift forward values of a group in crossfilter.js without breaking filters

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

I'm using dc.js to build a composite linechart where i can visualize analytics data from a period of time selected by the user on a line, and confront it with data from the precedent corrisponding period of time on another line.

For example if the selected range is this month, the confront line should show me last month data; if it's today, it should show me yesterday data. Something like google analytics dashboard's composite chart. 
So,in the image, the blue line represent data from 22/8 to 28/8, and the lightblue one represent past data from 21/8 to 15/8:
https://ibb.co/c7WCF9

I got it working, but i directly modified the values of a group, going against one of the "Crossfilter-Gotchas", so the filters now behave strangely like the Gotchas predicts. In fact, to create the group with past values, i simply shifted forward the actual values like this:

```
groupBySessionsConfront.all().forEach(function (item, index) {
    if (index - diffDays > 0) {
        item['value'] = parseInt(data[index-diffDays].sessions);
    } else {
        item['value'] = 0;
    }
});
```

Here's is a minimal fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0st1wbLe/8/.
By opening the console you can see the data of the confront group after the filter: the keys inside the filteRange are ok and consistent, but the others are wrong, sometimes negative while the dataset is all positive.

The question is: there is a way of obtaining this kind of confront chart, without having to modify a group directly, so without losing filters functionalities?

Comment: Does this question help at all? It's not exactly the same but has some similar characteristics: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51109998/676195

Comment: It solved all my problems. Despite i searched all over the internet i did non find it, shame on me. Thank you very much Gordon.

Comment: Awesome! I'm not surprised you didn't find it, as it's a completely different question that happens to have the same answer. :-)